# Rails4: change boolean value with ajax remotely

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

For example, I have a model `Post` with a boolean value called `active`, how can I easily change this value for `true` or `false` from the list of posts in the index.html.erb with a link_to or button_to helper like `remote: true`?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a controller method, say `toggle_active` to set the `active` status of your `post` like follow:

```
def toggle_active
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  status = !@post.active
  @post.active = status
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      render json: "success"
    else
      render json: "failure"
    end
  end
end
```

then, get a route to this action in your `routes.rb`:

```
get 'post/:id/toggle-active' => 'post#toggle_active'
```

this should give you a `toggle_active_post_path` or something similar.

that is the path that you will now target from inside your view, with the button_to, or link_to, as the case may be.

```
<%= link_to "Activate/Deactivate", toggle_active_post_path(id: post.id), remote: true %>
```

And yes, you set `remote: true` to enable the ajax call.

One more thing: you need to define a corresponding `toggle_active.js.erb` file, to handle the response from the ajax.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Another way of setting status would be using the built in Rails method "toggle" http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/toggle